# Global navigation (root) sites to drop down navigation?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss-3.0

I think Global Navigation for site collection always top navigation link. How can I change those links dropdown to root site.per example.

> Root Site | Site1 | Site2 | Site3 |
>   Site4 |....etc

I want change above links to

```
Root Site
   |
Site1
  |
Site2
  |
Site3
```

I can mange drop down navigation for subsites under any sites after root site. For example For "Site1" If I create subsites underneath, It will create drop down navigation.

But How can do same way for root site collection site. all its sub sites to drop down for root site.

Help me out.

MOSS and WSS3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit the master page (or create a custom master page).

If you are using the default master page, find the `SharePoint:AspMenu` control with an ID of `TopNavigationMenu`. Change `StaticDisplayLevels` from 2 to 1.

Comment: It is working for root navigation. When I click on sub site. Again Horizontal navigation with all sites is showing on sub site.  I want show drop down menu in all sites including root site. How to do that?

Comment: Is this a Publishing site? If it is, then it is more complicated because you will need a custom delegate control. If it is not a Publishing site, find the SiteMapDataSource control with an ID of topSiteMap in the master page. Remove StartingNodeUrl and then change SiteMapProvider to CombinedNavSiteMapProvider and ShowStartingNode to True.

Comment: Unfortunately it is Publishing site. Any idea on custom delegate control.

Comment: Take a look at 12\TEMPLATE\FEATURES\Navigation. I think you will need to activate a similar feature containing your own TopNavigationDataSource control (remember to make Sequence lower than 50). You can play around with the settings, but I think you need to set StartFromCurrentNode to false.